# How to store a list in a set or a dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I want to store a list in a dict or a set in python for quick access.

The issue is that I cannot convert it to a string or a tuple while pushing it in the set/dict.

How can I do push it in the set?

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways by which I can do this and **these may be considered as antipatterns in a lot of codebases, but it was a special requirement for our case.**

```
class ExtendedList(list):
    def __hash__(self):
         return hash(tuple(self)) # or hash(sum(self)) <- depending on the range of your data


original_list = [[1,2,3,...],[1,3,..],....] 
new_set_of_lists = {ExtendedList(i) for i in original_list}
```

Comment: You should note that modifying the list may make it impossible to find the element in the set again, *since the hash value would change*. [`frozenlist`](https://pypi.org/project/frozenlist/)s may be a more common route to take

Comment: This has no advantages over just using tuples (and `List.__hash__ = ExtendedList.__hash__` is either a NameError or useless, depending on what `List` is).

Comment: `list.__hash__ = ExtendedList.__hash__` raises a TypeError.

Comment: @MZ, I am well aware of that fact! As I suggested, this was something specific to our case.

Converting our list inside nested loops was much more time consuming than find hashes!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica , tested it, didn't work. removed it.

Comment: `frozenlist` route is available and known to almost everyone. The reason for creating this new post is to propose a novel solution.

Comment: This is a *bad* solution, because you can change the hash after you've added it to the set by modifying the list: ` `for i in new_set_of_lists: i.append(x)`. There's a *reason* `list` doesn't define `__hash__` itself.